# Use of any class / namespace with ZendFramwork

Tags: php, zend-framework, import, namespaces, zend-autoloader

> EDIT: Additional questions:
>
> - do I have to add the '.php' at the end of `new NAMSPACE_CLASSNAME`
> - Can I access any Zend package inside my controller / model, for
>     example:
>
> > /* Controller // Methods // inside a */
> >
> > method $client = new
> >     Zend_Http_Client('http://example.org',
> >     array(
> >         'maxredirects' => 0,
> >         'timeout'      => 30));

Hi there,

as I already asked [How to add 3rd party lib to the ZendFramework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566879/adding-3rd-party-library-to-zendframework), I also wanted to ask, whether my library is available in each of my `controllers`, `models`, `views` etc.
Does registering a namespace and autoloading its classes mean, that if I register `'MyClassXY_'` enables using *'MyClassXY_someMethod'*?

The other part of my question is about using any Zend internal class/component/method within my controller.
As I know from CakePHP I can do `App::import('appIwantToLoad')` or use a `component` to have any CakePHP class/component available at my controller/model.
ZendFramework seems a little bit different:
I heard about *'factory'* method(s) which instantiates for example a `Cache` `Object` using an array of parameters put into the factory method.

If you still do not understand what my problem is about, I try to give you a simple example:

I sit in front of my controller and I want to access the ACL or Cache module of ZendFramework.
I did not set any specific namespace to load (just 'Default_' to load) and I did not set any specific resource to load (except the FrontController and all other basic MVC ressources).

Now can I just use (`$Namespace_Module_AdditionalStuff`) 
`$ZendModuleXY = $Zend_Module_AdditionalStuff::constructionMethod` to globaly access this or that class or method?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set up autoloading for your MyClassXY lib, you can use any class under that dir. E.g:

```
//if there is library/MyClassXY/Foo.php with class MyClassXY_Foo
new MyClassXY_Foo
//is valid
```

b) You can store your bootstrapped resources in [Zend_Registry](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.registry.html).

```
Zend_Registry::set('dbConnection', $resource);

class App_Another_Class
{
    /* */
    $resource = Zend_Registry::get('dbConnection');
}
```

Comment: do I have to add .php or can I leave it?

Comment: @daemonfire300: it was a typo, sry.