# Include PHP Library in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have stored a third party php library in `/vendor/library` folder. Now i need to import it to my Zend app and use it inside controller action.

```
require_once ('/vendor/library/client.php');
```

Is this correct ? Or there is other way to to handle this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include third party lib in Zend Framework 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000465/how-to-include-third-party-lib-in-zend-framework-2)... basically: edit your composer.json file and run `php composer.phar install` again, to regen your autoloader and paths

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I can include any php files with composer like that ? Library that i use is not composer ready.

Comment: in the composer.json file, there's an `autoload` property. tp wjocj ypi cam add `psr-0` compliant libs, too... google how

Comment: Which version of ZF are we talking about here? When you say library, do you mean that single file client.php?

Comment: I updated composer.json and run it. I got   Problem 1
    - The requested package salesforce/library could not be found in any version
, there may be a typo in the package name.

Comment: @M.M. ZF2. Library has many files but as the documentation i only need to import one file - require_once ('soapclient/SforceEnterpriseClient.php');
 http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_Toolkit_for_PHP

Answer (score 2):

Use the ZF autoloader, then forget about include/require.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html

It means though that your class names and file names have to follow their naming conventions - which may be more trouble than it is worth.

But if you are developing your own library to work within ZF, then it is a good idea.

Comment: Note the path: `vendor` indicates composer is being used, and the tag zf2 indicates that a link to zf1.12 docs is not helpful

Comment: yay, zf2 tag added later I see. Oh well. So, vendor=composer, thx @Elias Van Ootegem

Comment: @Cups I can't rewrite that library. Its as Soap service which i downloaded. How can i include it without doing any changes ?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem So, where i should keep my external libraries in Zend ?

Comment: the vendor dir does not mean composer, anybody can name their vendor dir 'vendor', as many people do... since they put code their from different... vendors

Answer (score 2):

### Adding a Composer ready 3rd party library to a ZF2 instance

The correct way to add a 3rd party library is to use Composer.

E. g. if you wish to add [ZfcUser](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser) to your Zend Framework 2 application use the following command:

```
composer require zf-commons/zfc-user:dev-master
```

This will download the code from github and you just need to add the module name to your: `/config/application.config.php`.

### Adding other 3rd party library to a ZF2 instance

If your 3rd party library is not Composer ready, you can add it to your Zend Framework 2 instance by creating a Module for it.

**Step 1**

`/vendor/MyModule/Module.php`

```
<?php
namespace MyModule;

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface;

class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface
{
    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
            ),
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

What this basically provides is a way for you to register your 3rd party code within a file called `autoload_classmap.php`:

**Step 2**

`/vendor/MyModule/autoload_classmap.php`

```
<?php
return array(
    'MyModule\VendorLibrary' => __DIR__ . '/src/MyModule/VendorLibrary.php',
);
```

**Step 3**

Your 3rd party code should reside in:

`/vendor/MyModule/src/MyModule/VendorLibrary.php` and could read something like this:

```
<?php
namespace MyModule;

class VendorLibrary
{
    public function sayHi($name)
    {
        return "Hi there, $name!";
    }
    // your 3rd party code ...
}
```

**Step 4**

Add your new module to `application.config.php`:

`/config/application.config.php`

```
<?php
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        // your other modules here ...
        'MyModule'
    ),
    'module_listener_options' => array(
        'config_glob_paths'    => array(
            'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
        ),
        'module_paths' => array(
            './module',
            './vendor',
        ),
    ),
);
```

### Usage

In your Controller you now use your vendor class like:

```
$vendor = new \MyModule\VendorLibrary();
$hi = $vendor->sayHi('John');
```

While it is a lot easier to use require_once(), it is not advisable because:

1. it does not provide predictability and structure of your class hierarchy and location
2. you also need to take care of include paths and make sure require_once is present in all controllers that need the 3rd party features
3. it does not allow for overriding classes (Magento-style)
   etc.

Hope this helps!